# Meteor function executes before publish and subscribe finishes loading collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have meteor template helper with a function that searches for a document of scores. If it can't find a matching document, it creates a new one for the user. Unfortunately, the meteor function executes the `var score = UserScores.findOne();` before the publish and subscribe functions finish. Every time, a new UserScore document is created. If I turn on autopublish this problem goes away and it doesn't create a duplicate record. How can I ensure the publish and subscribe functions execute first, before the template helper executes?

Do I need to place a meteor method in the /lib folder for this to execute properly or is there a way to do it client-side?

```
var score = UserScores.findOne();

if(!score) {
score = {
    userId: Meteor.userId(),
    total: 0,
    goal: 200
};
UserScores.insert(score);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do Template-level subscriptions.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
    var subscription = this.subscribe('publicationName', publicationArguments);
}
```

That is a very simplified way of doing it, but you should have no problems with your helper running first.

Edit: The Discover Meteor blog has a great post about Template-level subscriptions. I highly recommend reading it: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

Comment: Thanks @SirCharlesWatson I need to start reading the Discover Media blog. That was quite helpful.

Comment: @CalebMarkov glad I could help! I highly recommend buying the Discover Meteor book. It is totally worth the money and covers basically everything you need to know.